# Url Rewriting doesn't work with Apache

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want the following:

`myhomepage.com` <- this should turn to this -> `myhomepage.com/index.php`

`myhomepage.com/mypage` <- should turn to this -> `myhomepage.com/index.php?page=mypage`

`myhomepage.com/mypage/mymethod` <- should turn to this -> `myhomepage.com/index.php?page=mypage&method=mymethod`

`myhomepage.com/api/logout` <- should turn to this -> `myhomepage/api/logout.php`

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ api/$1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&method=$2&item=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&method=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Everthing works as it should, but the rule with `api` doesn't seem to work.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ api/$1.php
```

When I call `myhomepage.com/api/logout` it rewrites it to `myhomepage.com/index.php?page=api&method=logout`

**UPDATE 2:**

My first thought was, maybe there is something like a default rewrite_module. Which rewrites everything what's not a file, to index.html or something like that. Especially when I use XAMPP.

**UPDATE 3:**

After experimenting a little bit, I found out, that I can't call it with `api` because it is a directory. When I rewrite this for example with `myhomepage.com/ap/logout` and `RewriteRule ^ap/(.*)$ api/$1.php` it works fine. Any ideas how to get this work with the directory name?

**UPDATE 4:**

I redirect the link todo.js (from host in Windows/System32/drivers/etc) to 127.0.0.1
then I edited the `httpd-vhosts.conf` and added the following:

```
<VirtualHost todo.js:80>
    ServerAdmin slajaa09@htlkaindorf.at
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/todo"
    ServerName todo.js
    ServerAlias todo.js
</VirtualHost>
```

And my `api` folder is a subdirectory of `htdocs/todo`

**SOLUTION: **

This is the final solution for my problem:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule api/([^/]+)/?$ api/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&method=$2&item=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Special thanks to anubhava!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading slash is not matched in `.htaccess` because `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Use these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule api/([^/]+)/?$ api/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&method=$2&item=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I had tested it properly before posting. Q1. Did you place it in DOCUMENT_ROOT? Q2. Do you have other rules in this .htaccess also? Q3. Do you have a .htaccess in `/api` folder as well?

Comment: A1. I have a internal redirect from todo.js to localhost/todo/
and there I've placed it. A2. Nope. A3 Nope

Comment: I hope api is the sub directory in todo directory. I edited my code accordingly. Can you try now?

Comment: okey. just tried something. This finally works for me `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule api/([^/]+)/?$ api/$1.php [L]`

Comment: but please update your post. make sure you remove the ^ before the api

Answer (score 1):

Your first rule,

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)/(.*)$ api/$1.php?item=$2
```

assumes that there will be a third path element, such as `/api/logout/stuff`.  For the case where there's no third element, you need to add another rule below it:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) api/$1.php
```

Comment: yeah, I forgot, that I want to add another element. But I tried it this way width just one element and it doesn't work either.